# Unable to use sculpt function

Tags: sculpting

I downloaded a 3D model by warfaremachine, and I am unable to use any of the sculpt functions. I have the desired shape key selected and set to 1000.

When the textures are disabled, the model is a darker gray than it should be, and sculpt tools don't even seem to work on the selected model. Is this a setting I don't know of, or a glitch?

Comment: i solved it. for some reason, warfare machine decided to invert the mask of this model.